# How can I "dye" an image?

Tags: colors, glsl, shader

I'm trying to make a fragment shader that takes in a texture from a spritesheet and a color. I want the texture to be different shades of the color given. e.g. when I use yellow I want the image to be different shades of yellow. When I put white I want it to be the original image. I have tried this:

```c
#version 330

in vec4 fColor;
in vec2 fTexture;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = texture2D(textureSampler, vec2(fTexture)) * fColor;
}
```

But that only removed the colors not present in the texture.
I tested it with a debug texture containing red, green, blue, yellow, cyan and magenta and when dyed yellow It becomes red, green, black, yellow, green, red. I want it to look similar to grayscale but with the color I'm giving it instead of gray.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think the problem is your texture isn't grayscale, you should convert it to grayscale first. Either you can do this before uploading the texture, or you can convert it within the shader.